# How to change the font-size of a button from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to change font size by click the button from the first activity? The changes made in next activity...Is this possible?

```
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v1)
       {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecActivity.class);

          intent.putExtra("fname",Text.getText().toString());
          startActivity(intent);
       }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation to your code about what you really want to do? I understood that when you press a button in first activity, you need to change the text size in the second activity. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, very easily by saving an integer value using SharedPreferences from the onClick then retrieving it and setting textwhatever.setTextSize("integer value");

Answer (score 0):

you can use the solution Smulinajulian is valid, or a simpler solution is to send as parameter the font size you want for

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecActivity.class);
intent.putExtra ("size", 
intent.putExtra ("fname" Text.getText (). 
startActivity (intent);
```

then the other activity gets of Extras the value of "size" and Sets txt.setSize ("int value")

Answer (score 0):

```
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v1)
       {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecActivity.class);
Bundle box = new Bundle();
        box.putInt("size", 33);
        box.putString("myString", ext.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(box);
          startActivity(intent);
       }
});
```

and in secActivity you can take value as

```
Bundle box = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = box.getString("myString");
        int size = box.getInt("size");
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        myText.setText(value);
        myText.setTextSize(size);
```